# Can't get distinct result from mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I want the distinct records by id in result,  but it is not working.
I have used following query,

```
SELECT distinct(b.`id`), b.`from_name`, b.`posted_on`, b.`subject`, a.`to` FROM `message` as b, `message_recepient` as a WHERE b.`id` in (15063,15106,15075,15170) AND b.`id` = a.`msg_id`
```

the returned data by query is

```
15063   John Doe    2013-03-18 07:18:15     hello       59640
15075   Dan Patrik  2013-04-09 06:27:04     hiiiiii     59640
15106   Rahul Y     2013-04-17 13:35:27     good morning    50452
15106   Rahul Y     2013-04-17 13:35:27     good morning    55129
15106   Rahul Y     2013-04-17 13:35:27     good morning    59610
15106   Rahul Y     2013-04-17 13:35:27     good morning    59622
15106   Rahul Y     2013-04-17 13:35:27     good morning    59640
15170   Ritesh D    2013-04-24 05:02:56     hi      59640
```

Comment: in the above table mention column names

Comment: `a.to` field is not unique. That's why it is giving multiple `b.id`.

Comment: and what columns values you want to see after `id` ? just random data? you want select distinct ids with last `posted_on` date ?

Comment: all columns mentioned in query, its necessary

Comment: If `a.to` field matters and cannot be excluded, then your query is doing its job already. Those rows are distinct because they have different values for `a.to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with join

```
SELECT distinct(b.`id`),b.`from_name`,b.`posted_on`,b.`subject`, a.`to` FROM `message` as b inner join `message_recepient` as a  on (b.`id` = a.`msg_id`) WHERE b.`id` in (15063,15106,15075,15170)
```

or ,

```
SELECT b.`id`,b.`from_name`,b.`posted_on`,b.`subject`, a.`to` FROM `message` as b inner join `message_recepient` as a  on (b.`id` = a.`msg_id`) WHERE b.`id` in (15063,15106,15075,15170) group by id
```